# Does Insights track the number of apprequests?

Tags: facebook, dialog, apprequests

I'm trying to see if Insights tracks the number of apprequests generated from an app. I can't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Developers Page: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Choose your app on the left hand-side, and click to **Edit App**

Then choose Insights on the left sidebar. Then click Sharing, scroll down to end. You will see Requests graph.